# How to insert into mysql with a server side AES encryption whilst having mysql recognize weird symbols?

Tags: php, encryption, aes, character

this is my first post and I'm very new with mysql and php.
I'm currently doing AES encryption for passwords.
I'm using this encryption: http://www.phpclasses.org/package/4238-PHP-Encrypt-and-decrypt-data-with-AES-in-pure-PHP.html since we don't have SSL security and must protect our server side as well.

It gives me an encrypted string like this : '�<�rB�5�]��MJ' and mysql fails at inserting the string even though I put the column type in unicode-general.

Can you help this poor damsel?
Thank you for your time.

```
 <?php
    $input = '123456';

function Encrypt($toEncrypt)
 {
   $Cipher = new AESCipher(AES::AES256);
   $password = 'superKeyHere'; 
   $cryptext = $Cipher->encrypt($toEncrypt, $password);
   return CleanUpString($cryptext);
 }

function Decrypt($toDecrypt)
{ 
  $Cipher = new AESCipher(AES::AES256); 
   $password = 'superKeyHere';
   $output = $Cipher->decrypt($toDecrypt, $password);
   return CleanUpString($output);
 }

 function CleanUpString($inp)
 {
    return str_replace(array("�", "ۓ"), array("=^_^=", "=^.^="), $inp); 
 } 

  $cryptext=Encrypt($input) ;
  //Encrypted
  print 'cryptext: '.$cryptext.'<br />';

   $oSql = new sql(0);
   $cryptext=mysql_real_escape_string($cryptext);
   $oSql->query("update userTab set pass='$cryptext' where id=1");

   $oSql = new sql(0);
   $oSql->query("select pass from userTab where id=1");
   $rows = $oSql->get_table_hash();
     $cryptext="";
    if (sizeof($rows) >0){
    $cryptext= $rows[0]["pass"];
    }
 $cryptext=Decrypt($cryptext);
 //Decrypted
 print 'message: '.$cryptext.'<br />'; 

 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

To store data that you encrypt, it is probably necessary to use some kind of BLOB field like VARBINARY.  Otherwise, MySQL will try to validate the data, which almost certainly will not be valid Unicode data.  Another possibility would be to convert the encrypted data to [Base64 encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64).  That data could then be stored in a Unicode (or even ANSI) field.

Answer (score 0):

In your particular case I recommend BASE16-encoding the encrypted data (BASE-16 is when each character is replaced by it's hex code, with 20 being for " "/space, 41 being for "A" etc). This way you get alphanumeric string which can be safely inserted into the DB.

And even better approach is to not keep passwords in the database, instead keeping the salt (some unique value) and hash of (password+salt). This is much more secure from many aspects.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the format Windows-1252. Maybe that works.